# Declare variable outside Widget build in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean, android-widget

I am trying to use a variable in other class, but it is not working. Why can't I declare orderChanged outside the Widget build?

**The code:**

```
class HomeButton extends StatefulWidget {

  static bool orderChanged;

  @override
  _HomeButtonState createState() => _HomeButtonState();
}

class _HomeButtonState extends State<HomeButton> {

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _orderChanged = false;
    bool orderChanged = _orderChanged;
    return
        .
        .
        .
       
  onPressed: () async {

     setState(() {
     _orderChanged = true;
    });
  }
   .
   .
   .
```

Thank you :)

Comment: the order change value is not changing. It is always false. Is this your problem?

Comment: No, it changes to true in the setState! The problem is to export _orderChanged as orderChanged outside the Widget build. I want to use orderChanged in another class!

Comment: one-word answer, you can't export like that

Comment: to use some variable value outside of the class use state management

Answer (score 1):

You should declare variable outside the build method as it builds again and again. Either you can declare `_HomeButtonState` class or `HomeButton`.
if you want to declare variable(that is orderChanged) in `HomeButton` (stateful class) you can access that variable using

```
widget.orderChanged;
```